# AWS websocket throwing CORS error while connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, cors, serverless-framework

I am working on the AWS WebSocket chat application using a serverless framework.

I have followed the [this article](https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-react-chat-app-with-aws-api-gateway-websockets-and-cognito-custom-authorizer-6f84f2da47ec) to develop websocket api

but when I try consume those websocket in my angualar application its throwing error

```
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is my chat module

```
mport { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'wss://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev', options: {} };
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'chat', component: ChatComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ChatComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),

  ],
  providers: [ChatService],
  exports: [ChatComponent]
})
export class ChatModule { }
```

here is my chat service:

```
export class ChatService {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }
  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit("sendMessage", msg);
  }
}
```

I have used the url which I got after sls deploy

[image]

Here is browser error:

[image]

Comment: You have AWS Lambda functions here, yes? Have you checked CloudWatch Logs for errors in your Lambda functions?

Comment: @Rhushikesh Hi, were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `cors:true` under `function.events` for all events to access them via cross origin in your `serverless.yml` file like :-

```
events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
          authorizer: authorizerFunc
          cors : true
```

and re-deploy the lambda.

Comment: cors is for http calls, But still I added but it not working